# DRF serializers how to best handle indirect references to a FK?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    
    thing_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, db_column='state_key', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    [...other fields unrelated to the question...]

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'THING'

class State(models.Model):
    state_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    flag = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'STATE'
```

And let's say I need to create new `Things` based on data received via POST requests.

And let's say these POST requests do NOT contain the FK of `Thing`, which is `state_key`, but actually the `flag` field from the `State` model.

What is the best way to implement serializers that help accomplish the following things:

1. Create a new `Thing` even though the `state_key` is unknown.
2. Return a serialized representation of the newly created `Thing` without exposing the `state_key`.

After reading and re-reading the documentation, the best I could do is the following. It works, but I'm suspect there's a much more straightforward way to do it:

```
class FlagField(serializers.RelatedField):      
    def to_representation(self, value):          
        return value.flag     
    def to_internal_value(self, data):         
        return State.objects.get(flag=data)  

class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):      
    state_flag = FlagField(queryset=State.objects.all(), source='state')     
    class Meta:         
        model = Thing
        exclude = ['state']
```

Is this an acceptable approach? If not, what is wrong with it and how else could I accomplish the goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's acceptable (this is how I have done similar in the past). In the general case, `to_internal_value` should also handle the possibilities of `DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned` exceptions around the `State.objects.get` query, so that your API can return an appropriate 4xx response instead of 500 error here.

Comment: Hmm, I'm realizing that indeed an inexistent flag crashes the program. I thought it would have resulted in is.valid() being False, but I guess I'm missing something here. Would you care to elaborate on how you would handle these errors?

Comment: You need to re-raise the correct kind of exception (`serializers.ValidationError`).

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks, it catches the errors like a charm now!